# How to confirm successful payment charge in stripe

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, stripe-payments

I want a confirmation that a charge was successful in stripe. I have the following that I think works fine:

```
 exports.chargecustomer = functions.database.ref('/Orders/{pushId}').onCreate((event) => {

     const original = event.data.val();
     const orderid = event.params.pushId;

     const token = original.paytoken;

     var orderstatus = {

         status: "charged"
     };

     var updates = {};
     updates['/Orders/' + orderid + "status"] = "charged";

     // Charge the user's card:
     stripe.charges.create({
         amount: 999,
         currency: "usd",
         description: "Example charge",
         source: token,


     }, function(err, charge) {

         console.log('error from charging', err);


         if (charge.paid === true) {

             //change status to charged
             console.log("the payment went through")
             return event.data.ref.parent.update(updates);


         } else {
             console.log("the payment did not go through")

         }

     });

 });
```

when I run this it says the err is null which I assumed the charge went through.

update: I was able to retrieve the charge attribute to know if the charge went through. I want to update the node that has the charge status from pending to charged but I don't know what is wrong with the code, no update is being done. What am doing wrongly and how can i update the "status" attribute in this path '/Orders/' +orderid to charged?

Comment: I think if the callback function indeed return a charge object, which mean the Stripe successfully charged the user's money, and by the way, it is a good idea to wrap the error code block inside a if statement

Answer (score -1):

The stripe sdk is confirming you about successful payment through success callback, if you want to intimate your self about successful payments, you can add here some alert like email